# Does ready two-way hash function for strings with fixed hash length exist in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I need use hash and en-hashed (two-way) function for strings. Hash should be fixed length (5-6 symbols).

Example:

```
String hashed = MagicHashLib.hash("long string"); //hash is hd45dk as an example
String enhashedLongString = MagicHashLib.enhash(hash);
```

Does exist already implemented algorithm in Java? Or I should write my own?

Comment: What's enhash..?

Comment: Hashes are supposed to be one-way. That makes a hash :) So, you may not be talking about hashing here, indeed.

Comment: do you mean encryption and decryption?`

Comment: An operation opposite to hashing. I haven't found correct antonym for "hashing", sorry

Comment: @Jun: Once hashed, there is no way to get the original String. It's a one-way function.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such hash exists, regardless of the programming language.

Here is a quote from the [hash function wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function):

```
A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of arbitrary size to data of fixed size.
```

It means that you have a fixed set of values, e.g. a 6 character long hash can store `16^6` different values. However, you can create the hash value of any string. So a hash function maps potentially infinite different values to a fixed sets of values. Hence there will be collisions. So you cannot tell just by the hash value which was the right original value.

A simplistic example from an imaginary hash function: `John` maps to `abc`. `Jane` maps to `ghi`. `Doe` also maps to `abc`. So when you see `abc` as a hashed value, where did that come from? Was it `John`? Was it `Doe`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Changed to `16^6` because that's the usual radix in hashes. But it's a matter of radix anyway. You can include other chars as &, #. But that would be weird :)

Comment: I got myself a bit confused here. You're probably right :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called **encryption and decryption**.

Hashing is **always one-way**. You cannot feasibly recover original string from its hashed value.

For brief explanation about differences between hashing and encryption [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms)

Comment: *You cannot recover original string from its hashed value*: not entirely correct. It just takes a very very very very very very very ... very very long time

Comment: Added the term "feasibly".

Comment: I see. Thank you!